# How to set the Ubuntu dock icon size to less then 16?

Tags: icons, resize, dock

In Ubuntu 20.04.1 settings, the minimum Dock icon size is 16:

[image: minimum dock size]

How can I set this to less then 16?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Install **dconf editor** from software center.
2. open it and go to `org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/`.
3. There you will find `dash-max-icon-size`.
4. Set the value whatever you want (The default value is 48).

Or just run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size <VALUE>
```

for example -

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size 13
```

[image: dconf-editor screenshot]

Comment: Super, works 100%. Thank you Ankit

Comment: After a reboot it may revert.

Comment: simple and precise thanks